# Watir Check Text exists

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver, assertion

I get it not the Watir in conjunction with rspec find my text.
The following code leads to this error.

1. Code:`browser.text.include?("Coverberechnung").should == true`
2. Error1: `expected: true got: false (using ==)`
3. Error2: `Using should from rspec-expectations' old :should syntax
   without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new
   :expect syntax or explicitly enable :should instead. Called from`

Maybe I can have a help

URL for the Site: [enter link description here](http://www.bod.de/hilfe/coverberechnung.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for an initially-capitalized string (i.e. *Coverberechnung*), but that string is all-capitalized on the test site (i.e. *COVERBERECHNUNG*).

Try:

`browser.text.include?("COVERBERECHNUNG").should == true`

or (using [expect](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers) syntax)

`expect(browser.text.include?("COVERBERECHNUNG")).to be true`

Comment: With the expect syntax I had to use 'to be true' instead of 'to be_true', other than that upvote ;). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use 
`expect(browser.text).to include('coverberechnung')`

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to be indifferent about case I would do something like this:

```
browser.text.upcase.include?("COVERBERECHNUNG").should == true
```

or

```
browser.text.downcase.include?("coverberechnung").should == true
```

this way you can avoid text comparison that may have varying cases.

also for you last problem #3:
use

```
expect(browser.text.downcase.include?("coverberechnung")).to be true
```

they deprecated that version some time ago. so you can give this one a try with no issue.

**NOTE**:  only one caveat is that this will ignore case. As described above.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do the following:

```
fail unless @browser.text.include? 'COVERBERECHNUNG'
```

Or if you want to target that exact string, you could do the following instead:

```
@browser.h1(text: 'COVERBERECHNUNG').wait_until_present
```

This code will raise an exception after 30 seconds (thus, failing your test in the process) if it can't find a header element with the text: 'COVERBERECHNUNG'. You can also override the waiting or polling process by doing the following:

```
@browser.h1(text: 'COVERBERECHNUNG').wait_until_present(10)
```

That code will check that h1 element within 10 seconds.